# Add link on a Div without content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a grid of divs created with Flex, the divs are empty, the only one thing I would like to do is add a link on these divs (on the single images, every image should have a different link).

I tried to add a link on a div in HTML but the div disappears.

Is it possible to add a link on a div with JS o Jquery? I tried in a lot of ways with HTML but without results.

This is the code of the grid:

https://jsfiddle.net/matteous1/3w9Lymwz/

HTML

```
<div class="contenitor-projects">
  <div class="row1-projects">
    <div id="proj1"></div>
    <div id="proj2"></div>
    <div id="proj3"></div>
    <div id="proj4"></div>
    <div id="proj1"></div>
    <div id="proj2"></div>
    <div id="proj3"></div>
    <div id="proj4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 body, html {
margin:0px;
padding: 0;
}
.contenitor-projects {

  height:100vh;
}
.row1-projects {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
}

#proj1 {
background: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200") center center no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
flex:1 0 25%; /* add this */
height:calc(100vh / 3);
margin:3px; /* add this */
}

#proj2 {
background: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200") center center no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
flex:1 0 25%; /* add this */
height:calc(100vh / 3);
margin:3px; /* add this */
}

#proj3 {
background: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200") center center no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
flex:1 0 25%;  /* add this */
height:calc(100vh / 3);
margin:3px; /* add this */
}

#proj4 {
background: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200") center center no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
flex:1 0 25%;  /* add this */ 
height:calc(100vh / 3); 
margin:3px; /* add this */
}
```

I tried to add the link in this way but the link disappear:

```
<div class="contenitor-projects">
  <div class="row1-projects">
    <a href="http://www.link.com"><div id="proj1"></div></a>
    <div id="proj2"></div>
    <div id="proj3"></div>
    <div id="proj4"></div>
    <div id="proj1"></div>
    <div id="proj2"></div>
    <div id="proj3"></div>
    <div id="proj4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `row1-projects` element is a flex container and your `proj1` elements flex items, so when you now wrap those flex items with the anchor, your  `#proj1` rules won't apply anymore when it comes to the flex properties, since now the anchors became the flex items.

And as the *new* flex items (the anchors) now doesn't have a width, they will collapse into almost nothing (and if you check in your fiddle you'll see the images in the first line is shifted a little to the right, and if you set the mouse immediately to the left of the first image, you'll see the cursor change and you can click there)

I suggest you set your anchors to be flex items, like this, as there is no need to have any extra element for the images.

*Since `id` should be unique, I also changed them to classes.*

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
}

.contenitor-projects {
  height: 100vh;
}

.row1-projects {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.proj1 {
  background: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200") center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  flex: 1 0 25%;
  /* add this */
  height: calc(100vh / 3);
  margin: 3px;
  /* add this */
}

.proj2 {
  background: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200") center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  flex: 1 0 25%;
  /* add this */
  height: calc(100vh / 3);
  margin: 3px;
  /* add this */
}

.proj3 {
  background: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200") center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  flex: 1 0 25%;
  /* add this */
  height: calc(100vh / 3);
  margin: 3px;
  /* add this */
}

.proj4 {
  background: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200") center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  flex: 1 0 25%;
  /* add this */
  height: calc(100vh / 3);
  margin: 3px;
  /* add this */
}
```

```html
<div class="contenitor-projects">
  <div class="row1-projects">
    <a class="proj1" href="http://www.link.com"></a>
    <a class="proj2" href="http://www.link.com"></a>
    <a class="proj3" href="http://www.link.com"></a>
    <a class="proj4" href="http://www.link.com"></a>
    <a class="proj1" href="http://www.link.com"></a>
    <a class="proj2" href="http://www.link.com"></a>
    <a class="proj3" href="http://www.link.com"></a>
    <a class="proj4" href="http://www.link.com"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hyperlinks (`<a>`) will only be visible if they have content. If you place an empty `<div>` into an `<a>`, there will be no content for anyone to click on and so, you won't see anything. Also, the `div` should contain the `a`, not the other way around.

Example of valid structure, but nothing to click:

```html
<div><a href="http://cnn.com"></a></div>
```

Example of valid structure with content to click on:

```html
<div><a href="http://cnn.com">CNN</a></div>
```

Because you are using a `div` with no content, it's height becomes zero, so you can't even click on the empty row created by the `div`, but you can force a size (with CSS) on the `div` and then there would be a space to click on.

Additionally, because you have an empty anchor, it has no width and similarly, there is no size for anyone to click on. But, you can force a width.

See this example and the CSS comments for explanations on how to make this work by forcing heights and widths on the elements.

```css
/* General rule for anchors that will allow you to see that the first two
   don't have any height or width (you don't see any yellow) */
a { background-color:yellow; }

/* You can see that this div first div has no height so instead of a box, you see a
   collapsed line */
#div1 { border:1px solid black;}

/* But, this one does and you do see a box. */
.hasHeight { height:1em; border:1px solid black;}

/* However, neither of those div elements contain an anchor element
   that, itself, has any content. And, since an anchor is an inline
   element, it's width is governed by its content. That's why neither
   of the first two links show any background color. Their widths are zero */
   
/* But, the third anchor has styling to give it the ability to have width and height,
   so, it's empty, but there is space to click on. */
#special { display:inline-block; width:10px; height:10px;}
```

```html
<div id="div1"><a href="http://cnn.com"></a></div>

<br>

<div class="hasHeight"><a href="http://cnn.com"></a></div>

<br>

<div class="hasHeight"><a id="special" href="http://cnn.com"></a></div>
```

Comment: @Johannes, I was updating my answer as you left your comment. See my updated answer for a more complete explanation and a solution.

Comment: Why the down vote? Clear answer that explains block element height defaults and inline element height/width defaults, with examples and solutions that are documented.

Comment: I down voted but retracted it after some consideration. Your answer doesn't solve the question, you simply explain how elements collapse with no content. You also wrote _the `div` should contain the `a`, not the other way around_, which is not true either, as it does not have to be that way. Check my answer, as it actually explains what is going on in OP's case.

Comment: @LGSon Actually, my answer does solve the problem by giving the elements height and width. Also, while (for validation purposed) an anchor *can* contain a div, for semantics, it's better the other way around.

Comment: In a way it does provide a solution, hence I retracted my vote.

Comment: @LGSon I appreciate that, but I would say that your answer provides a solution *"in a way"* as well. I would up vote your answer if it explained what the actual problem is, rather than just providing a solution. (My answer does both). ;)

Comment: My answer explains very well why the link doesn't work in OP's question, doesn't it?

Comment: @LGSon I don't think it does. You've abstracted the real problem by only discussing `flex`. The real issue is the lack of content and how block and inline elements determine their default sizes.

Comment: I added a second paragraph to my answer to explain what happened with the _new_ flex item

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like here:

https://jsfiddle.net/L1wbgox3/1/

I put the `a` tags *into*  the DIVs and applied `display: block;  width: 100%; height: 100%;` to them to make sure they fill the whole space of the parent DIV. (`a` tags are inline elements by default, so they wouldn't take up any space without that. THis is also the reason for your problem - if you wrap a DIV with an a tag, the link becomes an inline element without any size )

Answer (score -1):

You have to put the link inside the div, not the div inside the link.

The code should be like:

```
<div id="proj1"><a href="http://www.link.com">Link</a></div>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the question, and there is absolutely nothing wrong with putting a `div` inside an anchor

Answer (score -1):

Set `height` and `width` for a div in css.
Add the div in the  tag